# error in dealing with object in cpp

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to cpp. I face problem in the following code.
   I expect that when i call checkyo() again and again from main, the value of id should increase. However it remains the same.

**Entered if

check is = 1

check is = 1

check is = 1

check is = 1

check is = 1

Press any key to continue . . .**

**However, i expect the out put to be**

**Entered if

check is = 1

check is = 2

check is = 3

check is = 4

check is = 5

***Please point out my mistake?***

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
int count1;
using namespace std;

class A{
  int id;
 public:
 A(){
      id=0;          
  }

  void check()
  {
   ++id;
   cout<<"check is = " << id << endl;

   }   
  };    

 class B{

  vector<A> v;
public: 
    void checkyo()
   {
       if(count1==1)
       {
           cout<< "Entered if \n" ;
           A a;
           v.push_back(a);
       }
    A temp = v.back();
    temp.check();
   }

  };

int main()
 {   
    B b;
    count1 =1;
    b.checkyo();
    count1++;

    b.checkyo();
    b.checkyo();
    b.checkyo();
    b.checkyo();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in checkyo() function, you only push_back once then count1 is changed to 2, so `v` always has one element which output `1` in check() function.

```
A temp = v.back();
temp.check();
```

temp is always a copy of last element in `v`, it's not a reference to last element of v.

You could make a reference to last element of `v` which should give you the operation you want:

```
A &temp = v.back();
temp.check();
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you call `check()`, you create a temporary object

```
A temp = v.back();
temp.check();
```

The `id` of this temporary object is incremented, but not the `id`s in your `vector`'s objects.

When you call `checkyo()` again, there's a new temporary `A` with an `id` of `0`.
If you want to increment the last object in your vector, you must use a reference to this object

```
A &last = v.back();
last.check();
```

Now the last object isn't copied anymore and it's `id` is incremented by `1`, every time you call `checkyo()`.

Comment: I don't understand this. :-|
v.back() returns A reference to the last element in the vector. 
So where does come the concept if temporary object?

Comment: @check the one you return from `.back()` has a count of zero. A **copy** is made and stored in `temp`. The copie's `.check()` increments to one. The copy reports and is then destroyed. The next run does it all over again, but `.check()` is *never* invoked on the *actual* object at the back of your vector. It is always invoked on a copy of that object only. (and +1, btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig  
okay! 
Can i say that ** A temp = v.back() ** is entirely wrong. Since, v.back() returns a reference to the object and i should have assigned that to ** A& temp** rather than A temp ?????

Comment: `A temp = v.back()` makes a copy not reference ....

Comment: @check it may return a reference, but you're not *assigning* it to a *reference variable*. you're making a copy instead. See Olaf's updated answer (or Alex's, or Billz) for how to solve this using a reference variable. Sidebar: You *can* just `v.back().check()` if you want to, which invokes `.check()` on the *referenced* back element with no temp copy, but if you want to use a local var *and* update the vector's back element, your local needs to be a reference var.

Answer (score 1):

Change `A temp` to `A& temp`. You are copying it, rather than operating on the one in the vector.